# File Chooser for get a document on google drive

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem getting documents that I extract from google drive with file chooser but when I select it and it brings me the URI I can get the name and but when I create a File is empty.

1. getDataColumn:

   public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                      String[] selectionArgs) {

   ```
   Cursor cursor = null;
   final String column = "_data";
   final String[] projection = {
           column
   };

   try {
       cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
               null);
       if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

           final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
           return cursor.getString(column_index);
       }
   } finally {
       if (cursor != null)
           cursor.close();
   }
   return null;
   ```

   }

2.Code for get a path:

```
else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri) || isGoogleDriveUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null); }
```

3.Check the file size:

```
(new File(PathUtil.getPath( getActivity(), uri)).length() == 0){
   //alert
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain in detail what "I can get the name and but when I create a File is empty" means.

Comment: Thanks, The question was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Especially this part:

```
private String readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        inputStream));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}
fileInputStream.close();
parcelFileDescriptor.close();
return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing correct about any of the code that you have in your question. For example, there does not have to be a `_data` column available for querying any arbitrary `Uri`.

A `Uri` is not a file. You cannot get a filesystem path for one.

You do not show what this "file chooser" is that you are using. If it is `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, please understand that neither are a "file chooser". The `Uri` that you get back from those can be used with `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()`. That `DocumentFile` object has `getName()` and `length()` methods that you can use. `length()` will return the size of the content in bytes. `getName()` will return a "display name" that the user should recognize (but may not be a traditional filename).